# Devexpress Master Detail

Tags: c#, devexpress

How can I create for this project Master Detail but a want to create just detail section. Like the picture below. In the Pilot List section, when I click on the area that appears as a plus sign next to each person, the fields for that flights section are shown in the person. Here is the detail area "Flights".
Thanks for yours help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itYMV.png)

Comment: What is the data source for the first GridControl? A DataSet? List<T>? Typically you would just set the DataMember property for the child GridControl to the property containing the child collection.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this - [Master - detail - detail on two grids](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q450775/master-detail-detail-on-two-grids)

Description:

> That is, I have a DataSet with three tables: CustomerInfo, Detail, and
>   DetailInfo. The CustomerInfo table has a one-to-many relationship with
>   the Detail table. In its turn, the Detail table has a one-to-many
>   relationship with the DetailInfo one. I have created two BindingSource
>   components. The first one's DataSource property is set to DataSet and
>   the DataMember property - to "CustomerInfo". The second BindingSource
>   is bound to the first BindingSource, and its DataMember property is
>   set to the relationship name ("CustomerInfo_Detail"). A grid is bound
>   to the second BindingSource. This way, if I click the Retrieve Details
>   button, a corresponding detail level is created.

To display master-detail data within separate GridControls, use the approach described in the following code example: [How to Display Master-Detail Tables in Separate Grid Controls](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/E883.aspx).